# JS variable to PHP to Mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, json, encode

I'm trying to send a JS variable to my PHP using ajax post

```
 function post(){

       $.ajax({url:"myPHP.php", 
              data: {name: "John"},
              type: 'post',
              success: function(data){
              return true;    
              },
         });
    }
```

It sends to my PHP but let's say I'm trying to alert the variable to make sure, I get nothing but it only works when i encode the variable.

PHP

```
session_start();

$EID   = isset($_POST["name"])?$_POST["name"]:""; 

$EID = json_encode($EID);   
$_SESSION['EID'] =$EID;
echo "alert($EID);";
```

Now in another PHP file I want to do something with that variable but it's not working. It's like the variable isn't set.

```
session_start();

 $EID = $_SESSION['EID'];


    // Connect to MySQL
         if ( !( $database = mysql_connect( "localhost",
            "root", "" ) ) )                      
            die( "Could not connect to database </body></html>" );

    // open Events database
         if ( !mysql_select_db( "db", $database ) )
            die( "Could not open db database </body></html>" );

     $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM database WHERE ID = '$EID' ")
     or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());
```

The Query doesn't go through because $EID isn't defined or something like that. Is there a way to get the Json_encode variable as a PHP variable? Thanks

Comment: `session_start();
$EID   = isset($_POST["name"])?$_POST["name"]:""; 
$_SESSION['EID'] =$EID;
echo "eid = {$EID};";`

Comment: eid is the js variable?

Comment: No .. Do that and see what you get there . The code will print eid='value of eid got from js'

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$_POST` to retrieve the information sent by your [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request, but as seen in the previously linked documentation..  The default method is GET, not POST..  Use the `type` parameter in your settings to use POST(`type: 'post'`).

As to your ajax not returning results.. you do nothing with the data variable in your success function; all you do is `return true`.  If you want to see something done with the data, use it.

I would also like to state that in your ajax.. You have no item in your data object that contains the object property **id**, which would also account for it not being set in you php; to say it another way.. In your php, you retireve the value of the ajax request by using POST.. and you retrieve the value 'eid'.. but there is no 'eid', only 'name'.  Replace 'eid' with name, or correctly define 'eid' in your request object(`data: {name: 'john', eid: 'id'}`), and it will work.

Here is an example of the above,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myPHP.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        name: "John",
        eid: 1 //or whatever eid should be/put your variable here
    },
    success: function(data){
        return true;    
    },
 });
```

Comment: do what exactly with the success function? I'm new to ajax, sorry

Comment: @Kay Well, didn't you say you'd like to alert the variable or some such?  Example: `success: function(data) { console.log(data); },`

Comment: not really, I'm just alerting it to make sure the post went through. I really just want the variable to make a query in my DB

Comment: @Kay Well, I tested my answer on my end... it should work for you.  You aren't setting eid, and you aren't using the correct method in your request.  The default is GET, but you are using POST.. hence, it won't work.  My answer should solve your problem.

Comment: i'm sorry that was a mistake on my end. Post is defined and name is the post method as well. Still doesn't work

Comment: @Kay And did you define `eid` as I said?  You only have `name` defined so far.  If it doesn't work still.. please update your question with your actual code.

Comment: @Kay Thus far, I'm unable to reproduce your problem.  I have three pages, one ajax request, one ajax endpoint, and one result test.  So, what is the exact error message you receive from your sql query?  Also, I'm wondering how your database is designed, that an id is a json string.

Comment: That's the thing, I want my ID to not be a JSON string so I could successfully query my DB

Comment: @kay Then take out the `json_encode()`.  If that's your goal, I don't understand why it's in there.  Elsewise, you can always decode it with `json_decode($var,true)`.

Comment: if its not there, I still get nothing. Like if I alert the sent variable, it'll be "undefined" but if I encode it i get the variable alerted. But remember the aim isn't for the alert its for the query

Comment: @Kay Is the variable you're trying to add in the js global?  I don't see any variables passed to the `post()` function you have up there.  I realize that name is currently hard-coded in, but you spoke of a variable in your code, and I don't have much else to go on for the moment.

Comment: No I just used that as an eg. In my real code I have the variable defined in JS

Comment: @Kay Please post the rest of your code, because I cannot replicate your problem with what you have above.

Comment: @Kay I take it you've given up on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

===**Your Js**==

function post(){

```
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
           url:"myPHP.php", 
          data: {name: "John"},

          success: function(data){
            alert(data);    
          }
     });
}
```

post();

====**Your myPHP.php**====

```
 <?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE);// you may want to catch session errors on some server
session_start();
//connect to database
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "secret";
$database = "mydbName";

$connId = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Cannot connect to server");
$selectDb = mysql_select_db($database,$connId) or die("Cannot connect to database");

if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
$_SESSION['EID']=$_REQUEST['name'];
$EID=$_SESSION['EID'];
if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE ID = '$EID' "))
{
echo "Success!";
}
else
{
echo "Error!";
}
}//Closed isset here

    ?>
```

Comment: i basically copied everything you have, nothing echos nor alerts.

Comment: i dont understand how you are using your post(); is it when you click button or is it within other js functions

Comment: $_POST["name"] is this going to be your $EID = $_SESSION['EID']; and do you have this data in your database

Comment: try to Remove the "," after success: function(data){}

Comment: @ShapCyber the post function gets called when I click a link, yes the post variable is stored in a session

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you would be setting a session variable at all, unless you were going to use it your second PHP script for another, separate AJAX call. A session variable wouldn't be necessary to pass the variable to a second PHP script that was being included or required by the first.

And note that calling session_start() twice in the same PHP code will throw an error. If your first piece of PHP code is including the second, this would throw an ~E_NOTICE. If on the other hand your first piece of code is using PHP CLI to exec the second piece of code, the second script would not share the session data.